# How do you determine allocations under budget constraints?

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming

We have K people, and B choices to allocate from for each person (imagine for eg one of B movies being given to each of K persons) - each person gets utility U_k_b (you know this number) for the k, b pair. There is a budget constraint C_b for every allocation such that number of people allocated to (movie) b can be only <= C_b. Sum of C_b > K (given). How would you find an optimal allocation?

Answer (score 0):

(I discovered that) This is a version of the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) and can be solved using min cut - max flow methods.

Comment: https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/MaxFlow.html - here is where i found it